# Hide shipping and payment method for not logged in customer when traing to procceed checkout for a specific category of products

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, shipping-methods

I want to disable not logged in the customer to pay or see the shipping methods when they try to proceed checkout for the new arrivals products so what do i have to configure or override to do that. If anyone have an idea i will be thankful

Comment: this may help you
https://blog.mageworx.com/2016/08/an-easy-way-to-remove-a-payment-method-in-magento-2/

Comment: tahnks for your replay Amit , but  i want to remove this  shipping and payment method for not logged in for specific category not all  my category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `payment_method_is_active` event. On `payment_method_is_active` event,run an observer where you can disabled the paymenthod.

```
<?php
namespace Devamitbera\DisabledPgByCustomergroup\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class ObserverforDisabledPaymentgateway implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct() {}

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
      $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
      $method_instance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
      $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
      /* If Cusomer  is less 1 means user placing order as guest */
      if(null !== $quote &&  $quote->getCustomerId()  < 1  ){

               $result->isAvailable = false;

      }

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your replay , can you please tell me how to find this event

Comment: can you please explain that more to me thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I just found this article https://www.evermoretechnologies.com/blog/2017/11/magento-2-payment_method_is_active-observer/ and here is the content of DisablePaymentsMethods.php

```
protected $_customerInterface;
protected $_logger;

protected $_categoryFactory;
protected $_productFactory;

Protected $customerSession;


public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerInterface,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,

    LoggerInterface $logger
) {
    $this->_customerInterface = $customerInterface;
    $this->_logger = $logger;

    $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
}
/**
 * @param Observer $observer
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function execute(Observer $observer) {

    $productId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

    $product = $this->_productFactory->create()->load($productId);
    $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
    var_dump($cats);
    $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
    var_dump($quote->getCustomerId() );
    die("rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr123456");


        /* If Cusomer  is less 1 means user placing order as guest */


        if(null !== $quote &&  $quote->getCustomerId()  < 1 && in_array(20 , $cats) ){

            $result->isAvailable = false;

        }
    }
```

}

but when t try to acces to proceed checkout i have the reloader and nothing appear and my var_dump does not appear too can you please help me thanks in advance